# If I use jRuby, Ruby on Rails, and JDBC, can I still use an ORM?

Tags: jdbc, jruby

Can I use Hibernate, for example?  Active Record?  I have to use jdbc for an older database so I have to use jRuby with Ruby on Rails.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using JDBC and Active Record on JRuby in parallel. In my Rails application I have done it like this:

- the activerecord-jdbc module to connect to the database. This is my default

database.yml

`development:

    adapter: jdbc

    driver: 

    url: 

    username: user

    password: pass`


(test and production accordingly)

- some stuff is accessed via JDBC, the connection is retrieved through this:

ActiveRecord::Base.connection.instance_variable_get(:@connection)

Answer (score 0):

Using ActiveRecord should be possible, see [instructions here](http://wiki.jruby.org/wiki/Running_Rails_with_ActiveRecord-JDBC).

You can also use Hibernate directly by using JRuby's [Java interface](http://wiki.jruby.org/wiki/Calling_Java_from_JRuby), or maybe [with some Ruby sugar](http://olabini.com/projects/ribs/doc/).